# Why won't my ModalPopupExtender show? ASP.NET & javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net, function, show, modalpopupextender

I'm trying to call a modal popup extender from javascript. Here's the call:

```
function MyFunction()
   {alert("test");
   $find('mdlPassword').show;}
```

I get the alert when it's called, but the modal popup extender won't show. Here's the aspx stuff:

```
<!-- Popup Extenders Should Go Here -->
<asp:button id="Button1" runat="server" text="Button" style="display: none;" />
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mdlPassword" runat="server"
    targetcontrolid="Button1" popupcontrolid="pnlPassword" 
    popupdraghandlecontrolid="PopupHeader" drag="true">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:Panel ID="pnlPassword" style="display: none" runat="server">
<div class="PasswordPopup">
            <div id="PopupHeader">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="Controls">
                <center><table><tr>
                    <td>Please enter your password:</td><td><input type="password" name="Password" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><asp:linkbutton id="btnOK" runat="server" text="OK" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:linkbutton id="btnCancel" runat="server" text="Cancel" /></td></tr></table></center>
            </div>
 </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Jason

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML instead of the pre-rendered .aspx page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to define the ModalPopupExtender's BehaviorID:

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mdlPassword" runat="server"
    BehaviorID="mdlPassword"
    targetcontrolid="Button1" popupcontrolid="pnlPassword" 
    popupdraghandlecontrolid="PopupHeader" drag="true">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

> **BehaviorID**: In cases where you would like to access the client-side
>   behavior for your extender from script code in the client, you can set
>   this BehaviorID to simplify the process.

The script for showing and hiding the popup:

```
<script language="javascript">
   function showPopup()
   {
       $find('mdlPassword').show();
   }
   function hidePopup()
   {
       $find('mdlPassword').hide();
   }
</script>
```

- http://hocke.blogspot.com/2007/01/show-and-hide-modalpopupextender-from.html
- http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/08/the_everuseful_get_and_find_as.html

Comment: Actually, I wish I could give you two votes up. The extra time you took to list the definition, and explain *why* it works the way it does is simply A+

Comment: Remember that the trick with the BehaviorID [works with all Extender-controls](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/Walkthrough/ExtenderClasses.aspx)  inheriting from `ExtenderControlBase`. Glad i could help :)